# Get SASS to autocompile with NodeJS Express and node-sass

Tags: node.js, express, sass, node-sass

I'm developing using node.js, and instead of writing css would like to write SCSS files that auto-compile whenever I refresh the page.

How can I get SASS files to autocompile when using NodeJS, Express and node-sass.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

## Update (7 Dec 2014)

The connect middleware from [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) has been extracted into [node-sass-middleware](https://github.com/sass/node-sass-middleware), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27345470/396967)

---

## Install node-sass

In you project folder run:

```
$ npm install node-sass
```

## Modify app.js

Assuming you have generated your app using

```
$ express my_app
```

Your `app.js` should look somewhat like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes  = require('./routes');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

....
```

Here are the modifications:

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes  = require('./routes'),
    sass    = require('node-sass'), // We're adding the node-sass module
    path    = require('path');      // Also loading the path module

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);

  // notice that the following line has been removed
  // app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

  // adding the sass middleware
  app.use(
     sass.middleware({
         src: __dirname + '/sass', 
         dest: __dirname + '/public',
         debug: true,       
     })
  );   

  // The static middleware must come after the sass middleware
  app.use(express.static( path.join( __dirname, 'public' ) ) );
});
```

It is important to note that

```
app.use( sass.middleware ... );
```

must come before

```
app.use( express.static ... )
```

The reason is that we first want sass to compile any sass files that has changed, only then serve them (which is done by `express.static`).

## Restart your app

You'd have to restart your app in order for these changes to take place.

## Include it somewhere so it compiles

We can now include `app.scss` in our `/sass` folder. But it won't compile just yet. The sass middleware will only compile files that are requested by your applications, so we must include the (to be rendered) css file somewhere, like in `/views/layout.jade':

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="app.css")                 < we've added this
  body!= body `/views/layout.jade`
```

Notice that unlike `style.css` which is under the `stylesheets` sub-folder, the `app.css` is read from the root (in this case `/public`).

## Fixing paths

With

```
  app.use(
     sass.middleware({
         src: __dirname + '/sass', 
         dest: __dirname + '/public',
         debug: true,       
     })
  );
```

After the first compilation, the file and folder hierarchy will look like so:

```
Project folder
    app.js
    public
        app.css           < This is where the compiled file goes
        sytlesheets
            style.css
    sass
        app.scss          < This is where the sass file is
```

You may want to have the compiled output in the `stylesheets` folder, rather than the `public` one; like so:

```
Project folder
    app.js
    public
        sytlesheets
            app.css
            style.css
    sass
        app.scss
```

This way, the view will link to the css files like so:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/stylesheets/app.css")
```

However, if you change the sass middleware configuration to

```
  app.use(
     sass.middleware({
         src: __dirname + '/sass', 
         dest: __dirname + '/public/stylesheets',
         debug: true,       
     })
  );
```

things will go pear shape.

When linking to the css file like so:

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="stylesheets/app.css")
```

the resultant request will be for `stylesheets/app.css`. But since we gave the sass middleware the following config:

```
src: __dirname + '/sass',
```

it will go and look for `/sass/stylesheets/app.scss`, and no such file exists.

One solution is to keep the config as is, but the put all sass files in the subfolder `/sass/stylesheets/. But there is a better solution.

If you define a prefix config like so:

```
app.use(
    sass.middleware({
        src: __dirname + '/sass', 
        dest: __dirname + '/public/stylesheets',
        prefix:  '/stylesheets',                    // We've added prefix
     })
);
```

it will tell the sass compiler that request file will always be prefixed with `/stylesheets` and this prefix should be ignored, thus for a request for `/stylesheets/app.css`, the sass middleware will look for the file `/sass/app.scss` rather than `/sass/stylesheets/app.scss`.

## Final code

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes  = require('./routes'),
    sass    = require('node-sass'),
    path    = require('path');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);

  app.use(
     sass.middleware({
         src: __dirname + '/sass', 
         dest: __dirname + '/public/stylesheets',
         prefix:  '/stylesheets',
         debug: true,         
     })
  );   

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

});
```

layout.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/stylesheets/app.css")
  body!= body
```

Folders and files

```
Project folder
    app.js
    public
        sytlesheets
            app.css
            style.css
    sass
        app.scss
```

Comment: You should accept your answer as the correct answer if that's what it is.

Comment: While i now see your update at the top of this re @knyan, i originally missed it. Any way to make it more prominent?

Comment: @Pandem1c, I've done my best. Thanks for flagging it!

Comment: +1 for "It is important to note that sassMiddleware must come before express.static". Saved me a ton of time+energy

Comment: when i try to run sass.middleware, it says sass.middleware is not a function

Comment: @PranavSinghal this answer is more than 4 year old, and I have not used this technology for pretty much this long (webpack instead). So can't help!

Answer (score 37):

The connect middleware from [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) has been extracted into [node-sass-middleware](https://github.com/sass/node-sass-middleware). Use as follows:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path'),
  express = require('express'),
  sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware')

var app = module.exports = express();

// adding the sass middleware
app.use(
  sassMiddleware({
    src: __dirname + '/sass',
    dest: __dirname + '/src/css',
    debug: true,
  })
);

// The static middleware must come after the sass middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: You should add a comment to the [answer by izhaki](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23711898/177710) so that users will more easily find your valuable info :-)

Comment: @Oliver They only have to scroll down a tiny bit further. You can upvote my answer if you find it helpful ;)

Comment: @kynan please feel free to edit my post if the details within are incorrect. (Since posting I'm now doing my sass with grunt, so actually not using the code in my post anymore to check!)

Comment: Or at least put a comment at the top with 'Update' linking to your answer.

Comment: @Izhaki Done. Feel free to accept this answer if you think it's more relevant now.

Comment: It doesn't work if you use babel and mongoose connect